# Retrieving text from LPCTSTR with %S?

Tags: c++, string

I am currently logging:

```
LPCTSTR lpctstr 

add_log("%S", lpctstr );
```

but I am not getting the FULL text, the remaining characters are replaced with

```
ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ
```

I have done some research and I'm led to believe LPCTSTR is null terminated? So what is going wrong? lpctstr is a wide string, right?

What is the best way to retrieve the text for later use? Can I use std::string? (or wstring) static_cast gives me an error.

Comment: It depends if Unicode is defined or not. The "T" can be "W" or "A" based on unicode mode. Have you tried "%s"?

Comment: `LPCTSTR` *may* be a wide string (`LPCWSTR` is a wide string). It is indeed supposed to be NULL-terminated, and it does not seem to be the case here. How are you building that string?

Comment: @Lynn, nitpicking, but technically the `T` can be `W` or nothing. There is no `LPCASTR` alias, only `LPCSTR`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You know - after I typed that comment, I re-read it and thought... "I should really revise that. There is no `LPCASTR`... nah, nobody will be *that* nitpicky." :) Thanks for the comment for clarification.

Comment: @Lynn, heh :) Maybe I should kick back a little...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi FWIW, I think you nailed it with the null termination.

Comment: I don't recommend using `TCHAR` unless you want to support pre-millenium versions of Windows.

Comment: I have tried using %s but I only get the first character. http://pastebin.com/rt6GZbM2 is my log function i am using. I also have the length to the lpctstr so would it not be possivle to use std::string?